# Not able to identify AWSAccessKey while creating HIT

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create Amazon Mechanical Turk HIT using python script and I get the following issue. I verified my registeration in AMT Requester account and it seems fine. Could anyone let me know how to proceed. Following is the error :

```
raise MTurkRequestError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.mturk.connection.MTurkRequestError: MTurkRequestError: 200 OK
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<CreateHITResponse><OperationRequest><RequestId>aec5b15f-0ba9-413f-9443-1555152315c7</RequestId><Errors><Error><Code>AWS.NotAuthorized</Code>    <Message>The identity contained in the request is not authorized to use this AWSAccessKeyId (1454688645360 s)</Message></Error></Errors></OperationRequest></CreateHITResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely something with your access key. Check the following cases to make sure everything is correct:

a. One of the common errors is to have different username and password for mturk and aws accounts. Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html) for more information.

> Important
>   Your Amazon Mechanical Turk Requester account must be created using the same credentials (email address and password) as the root AWS account that you created in Step 1: Sign Up for an AWS Account.

b. If you create the IAM user make sure you have the appropriate permissions and if you use root username make sure you're using the credentials accordingly. Check **To manage your AWS security credentials** part [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html) for more information.